# print_r not allowing me to escape []

Tags: php

How can I escape the []? If I execute the following code, it just throws me an error

```
<?php 
$url = 'http://www.example.com/page/?type=software&sortby=title&sortdirection=asc&Name[]=make%3A%20microsoft'; 
$url_components = parse_url($url); 
parse_str($url_components['query'], $params); 
echo ' The '.print_r($params['Name[]']); 
?>
```

Comment: if i replace print_r with implode i get the same error

Comment: `print_r($params['Name'], true)`

Comment: @NigelRen the reason he is using `print_r` is because u_mulder requested he do that to DEBUG his code and understand why his prior question was giving the error. Using `print_r` was not suggested as a solution, but it was taken that way I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name is just `Name` and you should use `implode` to join the pieces back together.

```
echo ' The '. implode($params['Name']);
```

This assumes your parameter is always `Name[]`.